# BrokenCount <0 broken packages

Tags: package-management

I've had problems with my packages and Software Center for some time.

I can't download any packages, and can't open Software Center.
It says that I have `Brokencount <0`.

How can I fix my packages?

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: What is the full error? Is it saying anything about third party repositories? Or something about linux headers?

Comment: try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 1):

I think `sudo apt-get -f install` would be enough. Give it a try and report back.